# Indentation issues with Angular 17 and Prettier

Tags: angular, prettier

I recently upgraded my Angular project to Angular 17 and started refactoring the code. However, I'm encountering an issue with Prettier (version ^3.1) when formatting my templates. The indentation for @if and @for directives is not being handled correctly.

For instance, the following code should have proper indentation, but Prettier formats it without any:

```
@if(condition) {
@for(foo of data.foo; track foo) {
<div>{{foo}}</div>
}
}
```

This is what I wanted:

```
@if(condition) {
  @for(foo of data.foo; track foo) {
    <div>{{foo}}</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: latest prettier should support angular syntax. there is probably something wrong in configurations